# Python Class + Packet confusion

Tags: python, sockets, client, python-2.7, minecraft

I've started a project to write a python-based minecraft client/bot to connect to a standard minecraft server. I am using a library called [py-mine-client](http://code.google.com/p/py-mine-client/) to perform the packet handling. I've been having trouble receiving packets using the library - I don't know what functions to call / where the received data can be accessed. The main issue is figuring out how to receive the handshake response. I thought I could access it with the client.recievePacket function but it doesn't appear to be working.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
import string
from client import *

def main():
    client = Client("192.168.1.15")
    client.connect()
    client.handshake("MyUsername")
    handshake = string16("\x02")
    client.recieve_packet(handshake)
    client.login_request("MyUsername")
    client.listener.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Here is a wiki with info on how the protocol works:
http://wiki.vg/Protocol

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the library [source code](http://code.google.com/p/py-mine-client/source/browse/trunk/client.py), they have a `Listener` class collecting all packets in the separate thread automatically. The `receive_packet` method shouldn't be then called by the user (it's used by listener to report new incoming data). All packets are appended to `client.packets` array which you can access. Unfortunately, the library doesn't seem to be thread-safe (probably relies on the global lock) and they seem to have many socket-related bugs.

As the library seems to be very simple, you might like just to rewrite it.